# how to use each value of an array for each different element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array of 3 elements `arraylist = {10000, 7000, 2000}`.

I have 3 more elements `{1,2,5,7}, {1,3,4,5,7} and {1,3,4,6,7}`, where each of them are also arrays and I will get each of them from a loop. Each time the loop executes I will get an array like [1,2,5,7].

Now I want to execute each array `{1,2,5,7}, {1,3,4,5,7} or {1,3,4,6,7}` for only one value of `array`.

For example:
I want to execute

- `[1,2,5,7]` for the value `10000`,
- `[1,3,4,5,7]` for `7000`
- and `[1,3,4,6,7]` for `2000`.

I have tried to use `for each` loop but it does not fullfill my requirement.

Can anyone give me any solution or hint how to solve this problem??

Comment: _You_ are supposed to be the one giving _us_ hints about the problem.  So can you explain this a bit better?

Comment: is size gonna be same for both the arrays? I mean here the size of `array` is 3 and also `path` has 3 arrays. will it be true always?

Comment: You don't execute arrays. Do you mean you want to print them? Return them? What is the context of this within your code?

Comment: You need to use nested loops, for every occurrence of array element take one element from paths and loop through that element.

Comment: The size of array can be greater than that of path. But if there is a solution for same sized arrays then that will also be acceptable to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int array[] = {10000, 7000, 2000};
int paths[][] = {
        {1, 2, 5, 7},
        {1, 3, 4, 5, 7},
        {1, 3, 4, 6, 7}
    };
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    int arrayElm = array[i];     // Here you will get array Element e.g. 10000, 2000 etc..
    int pathElm[] = paths[i];    // Here you will get a path array e.g. [1, 2, 5, 7] etc..
    // Do your operation here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but path here is not an array. each element of path is an array.I will get these [1,2,5,7], [1,3,4,5,7] and [1,3,4,6,7] arrays for a loop.each time the loop executes i will get an array like [1,2,5,7] and I need to do my operation for only one value of array like (10000).

Comment: And it is what my code is doing. examine the code carefully. I am adding comment to help you.

Comment: But I don't have an array of paths. I am getting these [1,2,5,7], [1,3,4,5,7] and [1,3,4,6,7]  three arrays from another function using a loop. How can I get one value of array (i.e. 10000) for a value like [1,3,4,6,7] .

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like this, it will read and print on console.

`tempPath` should be an array.

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{    
     System.out.println(array[i]) // Prints element of array.
     tempPath = paths[i];
     for(int j=0;j<tempPath.length;j++)
       {
               System.out.println(tempPath[j]); //prints individual elements from Path Array                             
       }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but path here is not an array. each element of path is an array.I will get these [1,2,5,7], [1,3,4,5,7] and [1,3,4,6,7] arrays for a loop.each time the loop executes i will get an array like [1,2,5,7] and I need to do my operation for only one value of array like (10000).

Comment: Ok, what is the data type of path then ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you want some map, where `arraylist` contain keys, and `paths` is values.
For example you can use something like that:

```
List array = Arrays.asList(10000, 7000, 2000);
int paths[][] = {
        {1, 2, 5, 7},
        {1, 3, 4, 5, 7},
        {1, 3, 4, 6, 7}
};

int requiredKey = 7000;
int[] result = paths[array.indexOf(requiredKey)];
```

but better just keep all this data into some `Map`